# Throughput of Lightning Network

Tags: lightning-network, payment, statistics, lightning-nodes

Is there any reliable source of information regarding the estimation of the number of `payments` that occur in `Lightning Network` every day? If the total number is impossible to estimate are there any nodes that publish their `throughput` i.e. the number of payments they handle every day?

Answer (score 3):

as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L39IvFqTZk8) I showed that the [betweeness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betweenness_centrality) of a node on the fee graph is proportional to the expected routing fees which again is proportional to the throughput of your node.

So taking your throughput and dividing it by your betweeness centrality score should give you a rough estimate of how much throughput is handled by the network.

That being said. The betweeness centrality is constantly chaning as well as routing fees. Also the entire argument assumes a [uniform distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous)) of sender, receiver pairs (which is highly unlikely) Other than that there are no verifiable sources you can use. You will however find people publishing their logfiles or some statistics. All of that information has to be taken with doubt though

Comment: Thank you for the great answer and the very useful video. If you have any source of information regarding nodes that willingly publish their logfiles or stats let me know please as the 1ml website does not provide this information. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Nodes can choose to publish their throughput, but they can also stay private and go very anonymous by using the tor network for their node, this website aggregate most of the public node data https://1ml.com/statistics as they said:

> The statistics are aggregated and calculated from multiple nodes within the Lightning Network. Due to the decentralized nature of the Lightning Network, the numbers observed are approximations and nodes that don't broadcast their state are not included.

If you want to see the live update of one of the public node, just pick one of the most recent updated one: https://1ml.com/node?order=lastupdated

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was aware of this website but unfortunately it does not provide the information I want. The updated channels field corresponds to channel openings and closings as far as I know hence it has nothing to do with the number of routed payments. Thank you again!